# OrientDB Query works sometimes and at other times throws FormatException

Tags: c#, orientdb

I'm having a problem with this query below. I'm connecting to OrientDB using the C# driver and running the query in my c# code. All this code is in a loop and the queries in the try block works for a number of iterations and afterwards fails throwing a FormatException. At the point it fails I copy out the query and run it in the orientDB web interface and it returns the expect records so I'm sure it's not the input. So I'm so confused as to why it succeeds sometimes and fails at other times even when the input string is correct. Has anyone encountered a similar problem? Someone please help.

```
string origin = route[i].Trim();
string destination = route[i + 1].Trim();

List<ODocument> document = new List<ODocument>();

try
{

 document = database.Query("select from (traverse out_Connects from " + origin + ")     where in = " + destination);

 //document = database.Query("select from Connects where (out = " + origin + " and in = " + destination + ")");
}
catch (Exception e)
{
//document = database.Query("select from Connects where (out = " + origin + " and in = " + destination + ")");
}
```

[image]

Comment: Does it always fail on the same query value?  Are you sure there are no invisible characters in there that might not be there when you retry the operation?

Comment: Hi @Timbo , thanks for your help. The query fails on the same set values. I noticed that there was a leading space character but in OrientDB Web interface the query still works. then I trim the string values to remove the space characters and it still fails.

Comment: Can you post the full exception?

Comment: Hi @Lvca, the exception is a "FormatException: Input string was not in the correct format".

Comment: The exception it's on the client (c#) and it's related to the incoming date of wrong format. I don't see any dates in your queries. Can you display them or focus on them?

Comment: It's not the data because I evaluate the expression in the immediate window and enter that into OreintDB studio and it works fine. The set of data that caused the exception are displayed in the photo right beside the line (red) with the breakpoint. In case you can't see the picture clearly you can zoom the browser page. I noticed it happens at a particular amount iterations.